# How do you calculate the Monk's Attack bonus?

Tags: dnd-4e, monk

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to calculate the Monk's attack bonus, for some reason it seems stupidly low.

If an attack power has the keywords **Full Discipline**, **Implement**, **Psionic**. The power uses Dex and the attacker has a Dex modifier + 1/2 level of 4.  The attacker is attacking with a magic dagger +1.

The total Attack bonus I come up with for power's like Crane's Wings and Open the Gates of Battle is +5.

Are my calculations correct?

Does the monk always have what seems to be a low attack bonus?

Because he targets other defenses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Dexterity + Implement Bonus**

Like all other implement casters, you do not get weapon proficiency damage, because you don't use weapons as weapons. While it is slightly counterintuitive, the implement design of monk allows them to be mostly weapon agnostic and not attracted to fullblades like assassins. However, monks always attack NADs, so you're attacking level+12 versus level+14, and everything works out in the end. To improve this, take superior implement proficiency and implement expertise.

Comment: (plus half level)